# Retrieving Video Card Memory on cards with more than 4GB of memory

Tags: c++, memory, wmi, gpu

I'm using C++ to retrieve various hardware information utilizing WMI. I'm currently using the Win32_VideoController class and querying various information about video cards. However, as noted in their documentation, the AdapterRAM value returns back as an unsigned 32 bit integer. Thus, on higher end video cards such as the NVIDIA GTX 1080, the value does not ever exceed 4GB despite the card having more than 4GB of memory. See here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx

I've tried a different approach other than using WMI by using the DirectX SDK samples here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DirectX-Video-Memory-ee7d8319. Unfortunately, I'm still seeing the same behavior where higher end GPUs aren't returning >4GB of video memory.

Does anyone have any possible solutions or ideas on how else I could accurately retrieve video card specifications on higher end GPUs?

Comment: Obviously, if the API returns a 32-bit value in bytes, then more than 4GB is not possible to represent. A new API is required for that - either use a 64-bit value, or return the size in KB, MB or as some kind of "split value" - say 24 + 8, where one part is a "multiplier" and the other is a  "shift value". So 3MB would be 3 in the 24 bits, and 20 in the shift value. 4GB would be 1 in 24 bits, and 32 in the shift value. Easier to just extend it to 64 bits of course.